# Java AST to .java file Rascal

Tags: rascal

I am wondering if there are mechanics in place to translate from a Java AST back to a Java source file inside the lang::java::m3 library.

thanks!

Comment: see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703175/pretty-printing-ast-in-rascal/28705142#28705142

Comment: we have also had a prototype translating the Rascal-based ASTs back to JDT's ASTs. Now investigating.. will get back to you when we know more.

Comment: Great, thanks! Looks like I forgot about that question...

Comment: :-) just keep the questions coming Josh. We appreciate it.