# Pretty printing a Java Compilation Unit in Rascal

Tags: pretty-print, rascal

I have implemented a Rascal function that receives a **CompilationUnit**, performs some Java transformations, and then returns the resulting CompilationUnit (from `lang::java::m3::AST`). Is there any library function to pretty print a Java CompilationUnit back to a Java source file?

([There is a more or less related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703175/pretty-printing-ast-in-rascal))